# Gitlab Include yml - wget file from original yml not working

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have 2 repo. Repo A, Repo B.

at Repo B, I include the yml file from Repo A.

```
include:
  - project: 'test/A'
    ref: master
    file: '/.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

at the yml file of Repo A, it does wget file from Nexus Repo then extract it it to root

```
Trivy_container_scanning:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: $CI_REGISTRY/devops/trivy/trivy:0.20.1
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    IMAGE: "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - trivy image --reset
    - git config --global http.sslVerify false
    - git clone $CI_REPOSITORY_URL
    - echo "the project directory is - $CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - echo "the registry image is - $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
    - ls -la
    - trivy -h | grep cache
    - mkdir -p /root/.cache/trivy/db
    - ls -la
    - wget "https://test.com/repository/klass_inst/devops/trivydb/trivy-offline.db.tgz" --no-check-certificate
    - ls -la
    - cp "trivy-offline.db.tgz" "/root/.cache/trivy/db"
    - cd /root/.cache/trivy/db
    - tar xvf trivy-offline.db.tgz
    - ls -la
  script:
    - TRIVY_INSECURE=true trivy image --skip-update -f json -o "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/gl-container-scanning-report.json" $CI_REGISTRY/$IMAGE

  artifacts:
    reports:
      container_scanning: gl-container-scanning-report.json
```

The pipeline job of Repo B complaints that copy failed.

actually I saw that the wget isn't happen. Below is the job log :

How do I handle such situation, I thought the wget will happend in Repo B runner.

```
$ mkdir -p /root/.cache/trivy/db
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx    3 root     root            24 Oct 22 04:16 .
drwxrwxrwx    4 root     root            46 Oct 22 04:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            75 Oct 22 04:16 eval-trivy
$ cp "trivy-scanner/trivy-offline.db.tgz" "/root/.cache/trivy/db"
cp: can't stat 'trivy-scanner/trivy-offline.db.tgz': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Actually it should run on the Repo B context. Can you provide a copy of the whole `.gitlab-ci.yml` in Repo A?

Comment: @DanielCampos updated main post

Comment: Can show us the job-log or is the job not even started?

Comment: @akop the log already pasted in main post last section .as you can see mkdir works, ls la works, then cp failed. It is the question i asked why in between the wget not run.

Comment: Mhm, curios. Why the code and the logs not matching? (The error-log contains a directory in the `cp` command which differs from your code.)

Comment: @akop lets not focus on tha path issue. Because i have tried many ways to put files into different server to narrow down if that is connection issue. My guess it is not but more about gitlab or wget problem when cross refer.

Comment: I dont think, that it has to do with the cross-reference. But you can prove that. What happen, when you copy the `.gitlab-ci.yaml` to repo B? Are both repos using the same gitlab-runner? In Repo A the same script works fine?

Comment: @akop in short, yes no problem when ut is run individually without include reference to each other. Could you also tyoir gitlab a simple wget and simple include, did you see wget happend correctly?